# How to hook a Window Form within Microsft Excel from VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

[image]

I'm trying to hook a Window Form within Microsoft Excel itself like on the attached picture (This is an Addin called Kutools).
It is supposed to:

1. Fit on the right side of the Row number
2. Be Just below the name box
3. Be resizable and the window is resizable with it as well
4. Be collapsible or Expandable (like on the image)

I prefer to use the internal VBA of Excel to build and hook it as much as possible. But if I have to use an external Editor (Visual Studio C# or VB. Net ...) I'm willing to follow the instruction.

I searched all over the web but couldn't find a way to do this. I definitely appreciate your kind assistance on this.

Thanks for your help, I'm open to any suggestion!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-add-a-custom-task-pane-to-an-application?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thanks Tim Williams, this could exactly be a starting point to the quest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you are trying to create a custom task pane for Excel (add-in). If so, then this link might help you, but you need to build it with Visual studio using Office development tools:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/custom-task-panes?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thanks Rindra, I'll definitely read and try this. Tim Willians, in the comment referred me with a similar link. But I'll come back here with my feedback once I found a way. Blessings!

Comment: Thank you very much @Rindra, it seems like the term **Custom Task Pane** was the name that I needed to know for all my research. The Pane is working nicely now! God bless